# Javascript: assigning an input letter a specific value

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble assigning an input a certain value. For example, when the user enters a letter through the TicketType prompt, I want that letter to be converted into a number. So say they enter 'B' as their TicketType, I then want 'B' to be converted into 50 so I can latter calculate a total cost. At the moment TotalPayment is only displaying NaN and I'm so confused.

This is my JavaScript Code:

```
function ticket() {

    var TicketType;
    TicketType = prompt("Please enter the type of ticket you require!");
    document.write("<br>");
    var TicketQty;
    TicketQty = prompt("Please enter the number of tickets you require!");
    TicketQty = parseInt(TicketQty);
    document.write("Number of Tickets:" + TicketQty);
    document.write("<br>");
    var TotalPayment =(TicketPrice) * (TicketQty);
    document.write("Total Payment is:" + TotalPayment);
    var TicketPrice;
    TicketPrice = parseInt(TicketPrice);

    if (TicketType == A) {
        TicketPrice == 100;
    }
    else if (TicketType == B) {
        TicketPrice == 75;
    }
    else if (TicketType == C){
        TicketPrice == 50;
    }
    else {
        document.write("Invalid Ticket Type");
    }
}
```

This is my HTML Code:

```
<html>
<title>Ticket</title>
<h1>Ticket</h1>
<script src="test.js">   </script>
<script>calculate()</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var TicketType;
var TicketQty;
var TicketPrice;
function calculateticket() {
    TicketType = prompt("Please enter the type of ticket you require!");
    document.write("<br>");
    TicketQty = prompt("Please enter the number of tickets you require!");
    testType();
}

calculateticket();
function testType(){
    if(TicketType =='A' || TicketType == 'B' || TicketType == 'C'){
        if (TicketType == 'A') {
            TicketPrice = 100;
        } else if (TicketType == 'B') {
            TicketPrice = 75;
        }  else if (TicketType == 'C'){
          TicketPrice = 50;
        }
        
        TicketQty = parseInt(TicketQty);
        document.body.innerHTML += '<span id="text1"></span>';
        document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML = 'Total Payment is: '+TicketQty;
        document.write("<br>");
        var TotalPayment =(TicketPrice) * (TicketQty);
        document.body.innerHTML += '<span id="text2"></span>';
        document.getElementById('text2').innerHTML = 'Total Payment is: '+TotalPayment;
        TicketPrice = parseInt(TicketPrice);
    }
    else {
        if(document.getElementById('text1') != null){
            document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML = '';
        }
        if(document.getElementById('text2') != null){
            document.getElementById('text2').innerHTML = '';
        }
        document.write("Invalid Ticket Type");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! One more question: If the page displays invalid ticket type, can I make it so it only displays invalid ticket type and nothing else?

Comment: Hi Mithrandir, Try the snippet now. I have changed the code. Let me know if anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your string comparison is completely wrong.  I'm confining my answer to that because it's what you were asking about.

```
if (TicketType == A) {
```

Needs to be:

```
if (TicketType === "A") {
```

Also, you have to be clear on assignment '=' vs. comparison '=='.

Whole section should be more like this:

```
if (TicketType === "A") {
    TicketPrice = 100;
} else if (TicketType === "B") {
    TicketPrice = 75;
} else if (TicketType === "C")
    TicketPrice = 50;
else {
    document.write("Invalid Ticket Type");
}
```

Look into switch statements when you have a chained if-then-elseif

There are other things wrong with your code.  [Here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LfL0cs57/22/) with some fixes and improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change two things:

1: String comparation

```
if (TicketType == A)
```

to

```
if (TicketType == 'A')
```

2: wrong assign

```
TicketPrice == 100
```

to

```
TicketPrice = 100
```